# Quotient Rings: Quotient ring isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please help with the following problem! Thank you

Note that the irreducible polynomial $x^3 - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ has three zeros in $\mathbb{C}$ namely $\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$ ,where $\omega =e^{{2\pi i}/3} = - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a primitive 3rd root of $1$. We proved that if $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a zero of $f(x)$ then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x)) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. It therefore follows that the three fields $\mathbb{Q}[x](\sqrt[3]{2}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2)$ are isomorphic to each other, since they are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 2)$. Prove that they are nevertheless different from each other as subfields of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: $\omega$ is not equal to $(-1+\sqrt{3})/2$, because it is not real. We have $\omega=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$.

Comment: @claire, you're missing a minus sign in the square root of $\;3\;$ ...

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)\subsetneq \mathbb{R}$.